# R - Identify "Prime Examples" in Cluster Analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have performed a Cluster Analysis and as a result I got, lets say 4 different clusters. With $kcmem I can see which Station belongs to which Cluster. But I want to pick out one Station out of each Cluster and analyse it further.

I got this result (its only a test, I have more than 6 Stations). And I picked out 4 Clusters.

```
$kcmem
     4 5
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 3
[4,] 3 3
[5,] 4 4
[6,] 4 5
```

Of course I want to pick the Station that is the most typical one for each Cluster. How do I do that? From the main component analysis I know that actually there is a list of loadings and you can see how much a Station is related to a group.

I can only think that $kccentroids? But all Stations in the same Cluster have the same value then.

```
$kccentroids
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
4 1.0000000 0.5043308 0.7270394 0.7269328 0.6742015 0.6782120
4 0.5043308 1.0000000 0.5465914 0.5685687 0.6443715 0.5181649
4 0.7269861 0.5575801 0.9541015 0.9541015 0.8253911 0.8108125
4 0.6762068 0.5812682 0.7937889 0.8424147 0.9630949 0.9630949
```

Can anyone help? I would need a command that shows why a station belongs to a certain Cluster, so that I can pick out 1 Station of each Cluster as a "prime example".

Comment: This is not really a programming question. You would probably get a better response by posting this either on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)  OR [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I didnt know that this doesnt count as programming.

Comment: It \seems to me that this is not about the coding, but rather about what algorithm is appropriate.

Comment: Well, I thought I need a special code to get the Loadings. I dont see them in my "normal" Cluster output. Thats why I thought I need a command to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the station closest to the cluster centroid.

That would be the usual approach for KMeans.

If you use algorithms such as PAM (k medoids) or affinity propagation or minimax then these methods will naturally provide a cluster representative.